# in cloudera manager, how to migrate deleted datanode data

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I have been excluded datanode host "dn001" by "dfs_hosts_exclude.txt", and it works, how to also migrate datanode data from this "dn001" to other datanodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have to do anything.  Hadoop's HDFS should re-replicate any data lost on your data node.

From [HDFS Architecture - Data Disk Failure, Heartbeats and Re-Replication](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsDesign.html#Data_Disk_Failure_Heartbeats_and_Re-Replication)

> Each DataNode sends a Heartbeat message to the NameNode periodically. A network partition can cause a subset of DataNodes to lose connectivity with the NameNode. The NameNode detects this condition by the absence of a Heartbeat message. The NameNode marks DataNodes without recent Heartbeats as dead and does not forward any new IO requests to them. **Any data that was registered to a dead DataNode is not available to HDFS any more. DataNode death may cause the replication factor of some blocks to fall below their specified value. The NameNode constantly tracks which blocks need to be replicated and initiates replication whenever necessary**. The necessity for re-replication may arise due to many reasons: a DataNode may become unavailable, a replica may become corrupted, a hard disk on a DataNode may fail, or the replication factor of a file may be increased.